# Eclipse confused by GCC stringstream typedef

Tags: c++, eclipse

My Eclipse indexer annoyingly fails to resolve the target of the stringstream typedef, and sees errors all over the place.

By this I mean that, the indexer will properly annotate a `stringstream ss;` declaration, but it will complain over any further use of the object (e.g. `ss.str()`) with something like "method could not be resolved".

The following reproduces the behavior: in the menu, File > New > C++ Project > Hello World project, Linux GCC; then replace the contents with

```
#include <sstream>
int main() {
    std::stringstream ss; // fine
    ss.str(); // "method str could not be resolved"
    std::basic_stringstream<char> ss2;
    ss2.str(); // fine
}
```

I have tried various things, rebuilding the index, "cleaning the project", restarting Eclipse with `eclipse -clean`... For my real project I have also tried to delete the project from Eclipse, remove the .project/.cproject files and import it again (as a makefile project).

But to no avail so far, at least for my real project. Strangely enough for the Hello World projects a random combination of the above will sometimes solve the issue (and I may have, at some point, two Hello World projects in my list, one with the error one without it).

Also if I open the `iosfwd` header (that contains the `stringstream` declaration/typedef) `basic_stringstream` token appears white/unannotated unlike other class names (e.g. `basic_iostream` would appear green as a class name should). This is true regardless whether the project I access the declaration from sees stringstream::str as an error or not.

Versions:Eclipse-CDT 4.5.2/8.8.1, GCC 5.4.0

Any ideas where the problem may come from?

Comment: C++ is a very complicated language, syntax-wise. Only a full C++ compiler can fully parse and understand the syntax of a C++ program.

It is not surprising that UI-oriented development tools will sometimes fail to fully understand even a simple C++ construct, such as typedef. There's not much that can be done except to wait and hope that the next version of the tool will be a little bit smarter, and figure things out.

Answer (score 1):

I found a somewhat general hack that mostly fixes the problem:

```
#define stringstream basic_stringstream<char>
```

(through Project Properties > General > Paths and Symbols > Symbols)

Comment: That's not actually a #define, or e.g. the line `std::basic_stringstream<char> ss2;` would become `std::basic_basic_stringstream<char><char> ss2;`